# Can jQuery each() be used to modify each item(option) in a select list?

Tags: jquery

Given this select list:

```
<select id="my_list">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to do a jQuery that iterates over each of the option items and changes it to disabled when a certain condition of my each() statement is met.

I'm trying this (just as a test):

```
$('#my_list').each(function(){
    alert('test');
    if($(this).val()=='two')){
        $(this).css('background-color':'gray','padding':'10px');
    }
});
```

But the alert never fires to tell me its iterating over the values of the option list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that [you need a `#` in your selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector):

```
$('#my_list');
```

The second is that you need to select [the `option` elements](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector), not the `select`:

```
$('#my_list option')
```

The third problem is that you can't reliably style `option` and `select` elements anyway.

---

NB that you could achieve the code above by putting the [`value` check into the selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector):

```
$('#my_list option[value="two"]').css(...);
```

Comment: The fourth problem is that you should just be applying the style using a selector that finds items with that value instead of iterating through them using each()

Comment: Also would suggest the OP use addClass instead of setting css attributes directly.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here.  That doesn't match an element with id of my_list, and it certainly doesn't match the options.  This does:

```
$("#my_list").children()
```

Try something like the following to hide them:

```
$("#my_list").children().each(function() {$(this).wrap("<span>").hide();});
```

And the following to un-hide everything:

```
$('#my_list span').each(
    function () {
        var opt = $(this).find("option").show();
        $(this).replaceWith(opt);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('my_list span').each(function(i,item){...}
```

From there you have access to increment via i, or the $(this), which is redundant, and unnecessary.